# build JsonSerializable models in sub-modules with build_runner

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter project with sub-modules:

```
- root Flutter project
  - Flutter module 1
  - Flutter module 2
  ...
  - Flutter module N
```

Each module contains classes annotated with `@JsonSerializable()`.

Currently i build models with this script:

```
for dir in [DIR_LIST]
do
  echo "Building models in ${dir}"
  cd ${BASE_DIR}/${dir}
  flutter packages pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
done
```

Is there a way to build every sub-module in my project with a single command in the root directory instead of cycle each directory?

Comment: It may be feasible with `build.yaml` . See https://pub.dev/packages/build_config

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 4):

In your build.yaml file

1. Specify sources for your modules
2. Add them in generate_for block

   ```
    targets:
     $default:
       builders:
        json_serializable|json_serializable:
          generate_for:
            - "modules/data_module/**.dart"
      sources:
        - "lib/**"
        - "test/**"
        - "modules/data_module/**"
   ```

Comment: Depends on if the submodules are their own packages or not!