# dart modularization with build_runner

Tags: flutter, dart, build-runner

I have a project which consists of one runable project and multiple local packages. These packages are modules and a core framework. I am using json serialization and other packages which depend on `build_runner`. The problem I am facing is that if I add a class which needs `build_runner` to do it's work, I always have to navigate through the folders within the Terminal, and run the `build_runner` manually.
Is there a way to tell the `build_runner` to run on all local packages or at least ob the defined ones?

I have found an other SO Thread with quiet the same problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60374539/build-jsonserializable-models-in-sub-modules-with-build-runner), which suggests to use [build_config](https://pub.dev/packages/build_config) package, but I am not sure, if this task is possible with this package

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately I didn’t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone facing the same issue, I built a good workflow for myself which I want to share.

I am using VSCode, so I don't know how to act with this in Android Studio or any other IDE.

In VSCode, you can have multiple Terminals open. Go to *Terminal* => *New Terminal*. This will ask you which project you want that Terminal to be opened. There you can select your second project which depends on **build_runner** and from there, you can start a watcher with

```
flutter pub run build_runner watch
```

Whenever you do changes inside this second project, the **build_runner** will generate the desired files without the need to manually navigate through your projects